React app built using npm and parcel as a bundler is working on local server but not on github live pages
I have created a react application using npm with parcel as the bundler. It works properly on my local server. I upload it to my github repo and try to get a live working site for it using all the steps we find online. There is no build folder on my root directory when I run the command "npm run deploy". There is a .dist folder instead. It shows an error in the terminal as there is not build folder. I ran the command with .dist folder instead ""deploy": "gh-pages -d dist",". It is uploaded to the website but it's not loading any CSS and JavaScript to it. Only what's written on to the HTML page.
Here's the GitHub Repo This is the link to my repo. I have added the parcel-cache, dist and node_modules file to the gitignore.
Herse's the live site 
